# Installation of R fpc package

Tags: r, fpc

I'm having a particularly hard time trying to get the 'fpc' package in R to install on Ubuntu 13.04.

The code I've written contains a line like:

```
install.packages('fpc') ; library(fpc)
```

which gives the output:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
 trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> grep -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

I haven't messed around with the .Rprofile file yet, and googling the issue reveals that this may be the cause (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-October/055136.html) - the response here is pretty cryptic (and all I understand from this link is that I may not be setting a mirror).

Anyway, I've literally downloaded all packages from apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-*
```

and so far that hasn't fixed the issue. Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `help(install.packages)` you can see how to set a CRAN site in the call itself.  But for what it is worth, I use this line in my `~/.Rprofile`

```
## Default repo
local({r <- getOption("repos"); 
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.r-project.org"; options(repos=r)})
```

which I have broken over two lines here for the formatting. Adjust as needed for a local mirror.

Comment: Great! That seemed to do the trick. By the way, do you advise keeping my .Rprofile in my home directory?

Comment: The user's `.Rprofile` is in `$HOME`; I have also set this for multiple users in `$RHOME/etc/Rprofile.site`.  Your call, it is nice to have options.

Comment: I got the same error while I try to do sudo /usr/bin/R -e "devtools::install_github('rCharts','ramnathv')" on my linux server